# Script error: Cannot find path because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

Running a script but for some reason it gives me an error stating "folder does not exist" unless I've already navigated to the location.

e.g. I'm running the script with the PS console in c:\folder1
I point the script at c:\folder1 and it works and does what I need

If I run the script from c:\ and tell the script to check c:\folder1 it then tells me it can't access the directories in folder1 because they don't exist but there is clearly content in folder1

```
$User = read-host 'Input name'
$exportfile = Read-Host 'Save location of export'
$directory = read-host 'Directory to check'

$folders = gci -Directory $directory
foreach ($path in $folders)
{
  if ($path.PSIsContainer -eq $false)
  {
    continue
  }

$permission = (Get-Acl $path).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -match $User} | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights
If ($permission){
$permission | % {Write-Host " $($_.IdentityReference) has '$($_.FileSystemRights)' rights on folder $path"} 
$write = % {"$user $($_.IdentityReference) has '$($permission.FileSystemRights)' rights on folder $($path)"} | Out-File -FilePath $exportfile -NoClobber -Append

}
Else {
continue
}
}
```

Comment: Change `Get-Acl $path` -> `Get-Acl $path.FullName` or `$path |Get-Acl`

Comment: edit: Nevermind - got it. `$permission = (Get-Acl $path.FullName).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -match $User} | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights`